# Java method to write whole strings

Tags: java

I'm working with Java. I am using the AWT library class [`Robot`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Robot.html) to simulate interactions with a graphical user interface. The class has the following functions to simulate user key presses:

```
keyPress(int keycode)
keyRelease(int keycode)
```

I want to create a method for writing complete Strings (instead of a character simulating a key press) using the `Robot` class,  those strings should also support including the "`_`" character. I want to use the Java Class robot and these methods:

```
    Robot rob = new Robot();    
    rob.keyPress(keycode)    
    rob.keyRelease(keycode);
```

Comment: You need to put a lot more information. What is Robot? Is it a class you created or some other library class? What do you mean by 'writing whole strings'? How do you want to use Robot to achieve that? Why are those methods needed for 'writing whole strings'?

Comment: Okay, the Robot class in a libary class in Java which "simulate" to enter a letter to your front window. These Methods are implemented Methods in this class. I want to create a method to write whole strings, espacially with "_" in it.

Comment: So you want to write a complete string instead of a character using the Robot class? I think I understand what you mean

Comment: Have you tried simply calling the function ```keyPress``` multiple times inside a loop? Also, can you show the code for Robot class or if it is of a library, tell the name of the library?

Comment: String has a charAt(i) with i from. and then you need to translate the char to a keycode.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to just create a loop that goes over the characters of the string and perform a "key press" and "key release" for each character (simulating a user typing on their keyboard). Normally one would suggest something simple such as:

```
for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
// do something with char
}
```

But `Robot`'s `keyPress()` and `keyRelease()` do not take characters - they take keyboard key codes described by the `KeyEvent` class' static fields. You'd need to convert each character in the input string to the corresponding key code. The static method `KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(int char)` would probably work well: if you just cast the `char` to `int` you'd get the character's unicode codepoint index, which is probably what `getExtendedKeyCodeForChar()` wants (I have no experience with AWT, so I might be wrong here).